# Docker Julia dependency

Tags: docker, julia, julia-jump

Julia is installed on my host machine. Julia script runs very well from here.

I invoke docker with shared Julia installation directories. Julia script is run from these shared directories within docker (i.e. there is no julia image inside docker).

I get the following error:

ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to load

libpath47julia (/export/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/share/julia/site/v0.6/PATHSolver/deps/usr/lib/libpath47julia.so)

Comment: You should install Julia inside the docker image. Sharing directories just put dependencies inside docker.

Comment: I am using Knitro which is licensed and is present outside DOcker

Comment: Start mapping these so files one by one and see if that helps.

Comment: machine id seems to be different inside and outside docker. so Pkg.test("Knitro") is failing

Comment: You mean hostname or what? What does `Pkg.test("Knitro")` do?

Comment: so we managed to get a license for docker machine id and knitro test now works perfectly